# How could I form date interval with counts in R?

Tags: r, date, count

I have a date variable called `DATE` as follows:

```
DATE
2019-12-31
2020-01-01
2020-01-05
2020-01-09
2020-01-25
```

I am trying to return a result that counts the number of times the date occur in a week considering the Week variable starts from the minimum of DATE `variable`. So it would look something like this:

```
Week   Count
 1       3
 2       1
 3       0 
 4       1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We subtract `DATE` values with minimum `DATE` value to get the difference in days between `DATES`. We divide the difference by 7 to get it in weeks and `count` it. We then use `complete` to fill the missing week information.

```
df %>%
  dplyr::count(week = floor(as.integer(DATE - min(DATE))/7) + 1) %>%
  tidyr::complete(week = min(week):max(week), fill = list(n = 0))

#   week     n
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3
#2     2     1
#3     3     0
#4     4     1
```

If your `DATE` column is not of date class, first run this :

```
df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE)
```

Comment: But `llubridate::week()` counts week from 1st January. So it ignores the year part. I want the week variable starts from the `min(DATE)`. I have updated the question. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

From base R

```
dates <- c('2019-12-31','2020-01-01','2020-01-05','2020-01-09','2020-01-25')
weeks <- strftime(dates, format = "%V")
table(weeks)
```